# I can't open up URL's in Hotot

Tags: internet, lubuntu, hotot

When i click on any link an error message pops up saying "The specified location is not supported".

I'm using Lubuntu and hotot version 0.9.5.

Answer (score 2):

I see you've already  [filed a bug](http://code.google.com/p/hotot/issues/detail?id=213&q=url&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Reporter%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary) against Hotot.

**Please give this bug report a bit more time**, it seems to be legitimate. You can't expect feedback from the developers in such short order.

This will very probably be an incompatibility with Lubuntu/LXDE.
I've seen many projects which rely on things like "xdg-open" and gnome-default-applications
to handle urls and so on. Fixing this issue will require the Developers to make specific to LXDE, you'll have to be patient.

Update:

I've rummaged throught the Hotot source code, and found that it - if it detects you're running openbox - first tries to open the URL with `firefox` (it subsequently tries '**xdg-open**', 'google-chrome', 'chromium-browser', 'firefox' again, then 'x-www-browser'). It will open the URL (and assume all goes well) with *the first one it recognises as a command that is available on your system*.

After this, hotot can't do anything about error that is thrown by the software that was selected as probably being your default browser.

There's a [bug in Fedora's xdg-utils](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=580835) package which addressed an issue you might have; namely xdg-open not working properly with LXDE. The bug has been fixed in fedora 14, but it probably hasn't been pulled down by the people at Lubuntu.

So: it seems your bug report in Hotot is invalid, since they are doing everything properly. You will just have to wait for Lubuntu's version of xdg-utils to catch up to the current upstream version (as of the 28th of October).

You can  [file a bug against Lubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~lubuntu-desktop). The [better your bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), the faster it will fixed - as always. :)

Just make sure there's no issue with Firefox before you do.

Answer (score 2):

well i solved it and your comment was pointing me out to the right file where last months i hacked it to make dropbox get opened with pcmanfm and chromuim open downloaded file correctly so yeah the solution is i just had to put this in /usr/bin/xdg-open

```
enter generic)
#open_generic "$url"
#xdg-open "$url"
open_gnome "$url"
```

the "open_gnome" in the generic case since the others doesnt fit me

thanks again